# Order of indexers

Tags: magento2, reindex, catalog-price-rules, indexing, catalog-rules

On a Magento 2.2.8 store, we have a Catalog Price Rule for customer-group offers.

The indexers involved are set to update on schedule which is running successfully and not producing any errors. Most of the time this is fine and prices display as they should (ie reduced), however on occasion it seems that the price index is generated before the catalog product rule index has been generated and therefore the customer group rules are not taken into account.

Running a full reindex sorts this issue.

Is there a way to force an order to run the indexers or to ensure that prices are correctly displayed?